# Google Spreadsheet fetch data from 2D array

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I have below tabular data structure in a Google sheet:

```
           | A | B | C | ...
------------------------------------------------
2020-01-01 | 2 | 5 | 3 | ...
2020-01-02 | 1 | 7 | 2 | ...
2020-01-03 |...
...
```

I can neither use row index nor column index since I never know where 'A' will appear in the columns.

Please let me know how can I get the values of the cell having row: '2020-01-02' and column: 'B'.

*Note*: It is better if I can use a formula to get it rather than using Apps script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MATCH() to find the right column for a vlookup is traditionally how this is done.

Assuming your table was on Sheet1,

```
=VLOOKUP ("2020-01-02",Sheet1!A:Z, MATCH ("B",Sheet1!A1:Z1,0),0)
```

Or

```
=VLOOKUP (DATEVALUE("2020-01-02"),Sheet1!A:Z, MATCH ("B",Sheet1!A1:Z1,0),0)
```

Depending on the structure and formatting of the data.